# OpenDJ Administration Port (4444) not able to authenticate Default User(Directory Manager) /any user

Tags: java, linux, opendj, cacerts

Dears,

Could you advise me on below situation, am having an issue with OpenDJ DS after change JVM to OpenJDK
seems like the admin-certs has been removed from trusted store in Java
could you advise how we can recreate admin connector/certs in OpenDJ without re installing

config.ldif

```
dn: cn=Administration Connector,cn=config
objectClass: top
objectClass: ds-cfg-administration-connector
ds-cfg-trust-manager-provider: cn=Administration,cn=Trust Manager Providers,cn=config
cn: Administration Connector
ds-cfg-key-manager-provider: cn=Administration,cn=Key Manager Providers,cn=config
ds-cfg-listen-address: 0.0.0.0
ds-cfg-listen-port: 4444
ds-cfg-ssl-cert-nickname: admin-cert
```

Error even i put correct password

```
./dsconfig -v


>>>> Specify OpenDJ LDAP connection parameters

Directory server hostname or IP address [XXXX.XXX.XX]:

Directory server administration port number [4444]:

Administrator user bind DN [cn=Directory Manager]:

Password for user 'cn=Directory Manager':
Unable to connect to the server at XXXX.XXX.XX on port 4444.
Check this port is an administration port
```

Port status

```
lsof -nPi :4444

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    14530 ldap   87u  IPv6 4618018      0t0  TCP *:4444 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue:

2 things to resolve:

1. disable ipv6( not sure was this the reason)
2. on java (conf/java.security) comment out the jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms

Answer (score 0):

A change in JavaVM shouldn't affect the admin truststore which is located under the opends folder.
I would suggest that you try to use the Java SSL debugging flag to obtain a more specific error message that will help you understand where the issue lies (for details see https://ludopoitou.com/2011/06/29/opendj-troubleshooting-ldap-ssl-connections/).